# Display One more Image on top of that clicked grid item

Tags: android, image, gridview

I have grid view with 4 items,now onlclick of each grid item i need to display one more image on top of that clicked grid item.

How to acheive this?

[image: This is what is intended]

This is my adapter class get View:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    GridView.LayoutParams params = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
    view = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.tile_row, null);

    view.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    view.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
    convertView.setTag(view);

    params = new GridView.LayoutParams(Width, Height);
    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
    view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // set image view parameters
    setImageParamaeters(view.imageView);

    view.textView.setText(adapterNames.get(position));
    view.imageView.setImageResource(adapterIcondIds.get(position));

    if (params != null) {
    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    convertView.setId(position);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(onClickListeners.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: how many images do you want on top of the grid item after being clicked

Comment: only one image in the center

Comment: updated the answer with more explanation, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by positioning a popup window on top of the grid item. 
In order to find the exact on screen position of the grid Item you can use the following code

```
Rect loc = new Rect();
int[] location = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
loc.left = location[0];
loc.top = location[1];
loc.right = loc.left + view.getWidth();
loc.bottom = loc.top + view.getHeight();
```

The variable `loc` holds the exact on screen location of the `view` that was clicked, this is nothing but the 2nd paramter of the method

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
```

With this information you can easily achieve what you need. Best is to calculate the center of the view and align the center of the popup to the center of the clicked view.

**Note:You will need adjustments for showing the pop up in case part of the view is visible.**

**Edited:**
Since i did not get your question, i am adding an image to bring more clarity.

I have already provided the code for case 1. For case 2 you will need a modified layout where you can show the overlay images on click of the grid item
[image: Possible cases]

**Edited: Implementing case 2**

Modified adapter code, moved around some variables for optimization

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ...){
    inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
...
}
LayoutInflater inflator;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.tile_row, null);

        view.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        view.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
        view.clickedImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clickedImage);
        convertView.setTag(view);
    } else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // set image view parameters
    view.textView.setText(adapterNames.get(position));
    view.imageView.setImageResource(adapterIcondIds.get(position));
    //add a int variable to the view holder
    view.position = position;
    if(position != clickedPosition){
        view.clickedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
            clickedPosition = holder.position;
            holder.clickedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //you can also set the resource of the imageview here.
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
//this is used for resetting the previous view when a new view is clicked
int clickedPosition = -1;
```

> To preserve the clicked state of an item in the grid view, i store the
>   clicked item position of the grid. Now in onClick i change visibility
>   of the clicked image(which was in GONE state), update the variable
>   clickedPosition and simply call notifyDataSetChanged. This tells that
>   the adapter that the dataset has changed and getView for all the
>   visible grid items will be called. So, if you click item 1 initially,
>   and then click item 3 then you will notice that item 1 has been reset
>   when item 3 was clicked.

XML  `title_row.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/droid_logo_black"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clickedImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/login_help_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey i want to show one more image on top of the clicked grid item, but you answer is something different here

Comment: can you add a diagram to explain, what i get is, if you click item 3, them item 3 is pushed down to 4 and an additional image is added at position 3, if that is the case its pretty simple, if you confirm i can add some more code

Comment: No, my grid items are not changing they remain whereever there are, its just that onclick of one item display one more image of top of that clicked item

Comment: Hey thanks, you are exactly right in the case 2, but my problem is i am not using xml i am progrmatically adding the grid view. but i am not getting how to do it

Comment: post your adapter code, i'll modify it, but any reason why you are not using xml, using xml helps in designing the view quickly and in a better way

Comment: got any idea? how to proceed with this buddy?

Comment: please wait i will try this and let you know

Comment: hey one small question , i have onlclick outside like this ,  public OnClickListener ButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() { now i how do i get the clicked postion and notifysetdatachanged method?

Comment: use `#adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, for position, i am adding the position to the view holder, so you can get the position as well or else you can get the position if you use `OnItemClickListener`. Please accept the answer if it helped u

Comment: its working great but, i am not getting why you have given int clickedPosition = -1; and what we are doing in onclick method can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

In the onClickListener of the element, call the imageView and load the image dynamically.
Or predefine the image resource, and call the Imageview with the id of the new image.

Comment: dude there is only option to set the image as background? but how so you set it as froeground?

Answer (score 0):

`onlclick of each grid item i need to display one more image on top of that clicked grid item.`

I think you have to create custom Gird View. and append ImageView Dynamically as per the needs.

`setVisibilty(View.Visible)`  when you want to show and `setVisibilty(View.Hide)` when you don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + StringGenerated, null,     null);
```

Try something of this sort and you'll get the id. Try changing the image using

```
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```

Good Luck!